# Change default code snippet in overridden method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overriding, code-snippets

Please help me! Can i somehow customize auto-generated code snippet displayed in overridden method body by default?

by default overridden method looks like

```
public override void Method(int A, object B)
{
    base.Method(A, B);
}
```

i want to replace default code snippet with my own, e.g.

```
public override void Method(int A, object B)
{
    if (A > 0)
    {
        // some code..
    }
    else
    {
        // some code..
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

i have base class

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public int Result {get;set;}

   // This method depends on result
   protected virtual void Method() {}
}
```

there is a lot of classes, that are derived from the BaseClass. All of them have to process Result property in Method() in same way. So, i want to place some code, wich shows how to use it. 
According to my idea when i type "override" and select "Method()" in intelisense list i get following code:

```
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        // u have to check result property
        if(result > 0)
        {
            // if result is positive do some logic
        }
    }
}
```

instead of default code snippet

```
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        base.Method();
    }
}
```

**FINALLY**

Using [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern is a good idea for such cases.

Thank you all for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: no, i want insert my own custom code instead of default snippet, is it possible?

Comment: What is doing the autogenerating?

Answer (score 4):

In the [Code Snippets Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5941d54.aspx) in visual studio you can modify the [MethodOverrideStub.snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5fd0h9w.aspx)

Getting the sort of behaviour you want where the parameters are used in the snippet will probably tricky - I'm looking into that at the moment but nothing obvious leaps out.

However, just inserting the if/else with some template areas should not be too hard to do.

Comment: In fact i need to customize overridden code snippet for one specific method. I want that any time when somebody overrides this method he can see a kind of "example code". This code doesnt depend on input params, it is like "hardcode". I ll try to describe it in detail. Watch my post plz.

Comment: @garek I don't fancy your luck of changing the override behaviour for just one method (though I'll do some more digging tonight to see if I can find a way) what might work best for you is create a new expansion snippet that inserts the code you want. It won't give you the intellisense when override is types by will allow the moethod stub to be created quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Well, depending on a code snippet to have people write your methods correctly is not a good idea. If you want that method to *always* have that structure, you'd be better off using the [Template Method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // this method forces that structure upon the subclasses
    public void Foo()
    {
        if(result > 0)
        {
            DoFoo();
        }
    }
    // this is the method that subclasses override
    protected abstract void DoFoo();
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override DoFoo()
    {
        // now you write the code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, Martinho Fernandes! 
Using Template Method pattern in my case is a bloody good choice!